# How can I ask Jekyll not to translate double less sign into a Unicode character?

Tags: unicode, markdown, jekyll, github-flavored-markdown

I write a blog using Jekyll.

In normal text, double less sign, << is translated to a Unicode character.

How can I suppress this automatic translation locally in Markdown?

Answer (score 0):

Following

https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/279728

the answer is to use HTML code for the less than sign:

```
&lt;
```